# Python: opencv video and mutithreading in function

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, opencv

In my application, I have one function which streams opencv video. During video streaming, if there is an event, then one thread supposed to start which is having time.sleep().
I have tried using the below-mentioned code. The problem is it is only displaying one frame and then the video stream terminates. What am I doing wrong? I also do not have the liberty to use 'While True' loop for the video streaming.

```
import threading 
import time
import numpy as np
import cv2

# --- functions ---
def print_hello():
    print("Hello")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("World")

# --- loop ---
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def show_frame():
    global t
    t = None
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if key == ord('t'):
         if t is None or not t.is_alive():
            t = threading.Thread(target=print_hello)  
            t.start()
        else:
            print('previous thread is still running')
        
# --- after loop ---
if __name__ == '__main__':
    show_frame()
    if t is not None:
        t.join() 
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Run imshow in thread

Comment: Your program only captures one frame. Why do you think it will continue after that?